# How to calculate variance on spending?

Tags: statistics, average

My maths is a little rusty, but I understand how to calculate variance in general. A colleague asked me if I knew how to calculate the percentage variance on budget spending.

*Given this example:*

> The first budget for a project was 5000 dollars, and the department
>   spent 2500 dollars. The next budget was 5000 dollars again, but the
>   department spent 6000 dollars. Calculate the variance percentage on
>   spending.

How do I interpret this question, and will someone please give me a shove in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think that is correct because I think the numerator should be a portion of the denominator.  But you are using a center for the denominator of 5000 that is different from the center in the numerator 4500.  So in theory you could have a quantity greater than 100%.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I showed my answer to my colleague and it coincided with his calculations, so he was satisfied. Unfortunately I do not have the time to dig deeper at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Variance in spending (without considering budget):

```
Average spending = (2500+6000)/2 = 4250

Variance = ((2500-4250)^2)+(6000-4250)^2)/2
              = (3062500+ 3062500)/2
              = 153150
```

Variance against budget:

```
Variance = ((2500-5000)^2)+(6000-5000)^2)/2
             = (6250000+1000000)/2
             = 3625000
```

Percentage variance:

```
153150/3625000*100 = 42.24%
```